# How to run node.js with gulp inside docker and find the right bashsrc

Tags: bash, docker, gulp

I am new to Docker and I do have some problems.

My goal:

- use the Dockerfile to create a docker-container and stay inside the container  / don't drop out of it.
- running a local Docker-Container
- installing "gulp" with the package.json
- installing "gulp global" on Docker
- copy any files to my Docker container
- execute "gulp --version" and the default "gulp task" and stay inside the terminal.

Here is my setup:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --global gulp-cli
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["gulp --version" , "gulp"]  or? [gulp --version , gulp]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing Docker",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
function defaultTask(cb) {
 console.log("Default task for gulp 4.0 for docker")
  cb();
} 
exports.default = defaultTask
```

docker-compose.yml  (I don't think we need this for my question but I will post it anyway since I am not exactly sure If this could make some problems)

```
version: '3'
services:
  html:
    container_name: gulp-docker-test
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
```

My problems right now:

First of all I am really confused about the workflow of docker.
Do I understand it correctly if I run:

```
docker build . --tag gulp-docker-test
```

I will create a new docker-container on my computer with the content of the dockerfile?
If I need to update anything inside it I have to run it again so the container is updated?

If I use:

```
docker start gulp-docker-test
```

it will start the container? What if I change anything inside it? Will it be back on reboot of the container? Or is it gone because it is only a temporary image?

Beside that if I try to run it I get this error:

```
ERROR: for gulp-docker-test  Cannot start service html: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"gulp --version\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for html  Cannot start service html: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"gulp --version\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I did try those things: execute it with exec, removing the quotes inside the CMD of the Dockerfile but I think I do have some basic knowledge missing. I don't understand how to boot this container inside the shell so docker knows the $path.

Thank you for your help in advance

Edit:

I did found out how to run docker with the shell.

```
docker run -it --entrypoint bash  gulp-docker-test3
```

```
root@8a27dc3a9c85:/usr/src/app# gulp -v
[15:01:53] CLI version 2.0.1
[15:01:53] Local version 4.0.0
root@8a27dc3a9c85:/usr/src/app# gulp 
[15:02:38] Using gulpfile /usr/src/app/gulpfile.js
[15:02:38] Starting 'default'...
Default Task von Gulp 4.0 für Docker
[15:02:38] Finished 'default' after 4.28 ms
root@8a27dc3a9c85:/usr/src/app#
```

It looks like it should work if I can add default bash to the dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I run `docker build` I will create a new container?

It will *execute* the contents of the Dockerfile, and create a new *image*.

You need to `docker run` (or, rarely, `docker create`) the image to create a container from it.  When you update the Dockerfile or your application source, you need to repeat the `docker build` step, `docker stop && docker rm` the existing container, and `docker run` a new one.  Your `docker-compose.yml` fragment encapsulates this, but note that Docker Compose will delete and recreate a container when it's appropriate.

> If I use `docker start gulp-docker-test`...

It will start a *container* with that name.  That's a separate namespace from the image namespace.  The container has to already exist and be stopped (usually from an explicit `docker stop` command).  This is a slightly unusual state to be in.

> `CMD ["gulp --version" , "gulp"]`

This looks for a binary named `gulp --version`, and runs it with a single parameter `gulp`.  Since you probably don't have a single file named `/usr/local/bin/gulp --version` (with the spaces and "version" as part of the filename) you get an error.

You only get *one* CMD in a Dockerfile.  (Or one ENTRYPOINT instead, but I tend to find CMD preferable except in a couple of extremely specific cases.)  Each "word" you'd type in a shell becomes a separate "word" in the syntax.  So you could, for instance, write

```
CMD ["gulp", "--version"]
```

Alternatively, if you leave off the brackets, Docker will wrap the CMD text in `sh -c ...`, so something closer to what you actually wrote is

```
CMD gulp --version && gulp
```

In practice you'd usually run build tools like Gulp as part of building the image, and use the CMD to actually start your application.

```
RUN gulp
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I still have one problem:

How to stay inside the shell with this approach? It is quitting immediately. In my later workflow it could very well be that I want to use commands like: "gulp rebuild:images" etc. and for that reason I don't want to quit it.

I will mark your answer as the best one.

Comment: You could, I suppose, do something like `CMD gulp && sh`, which would probably result in an interactive shell.  Personally I find it effective to have a good non-Docker development environment (in Node all of your dependencies are locally isolated in the `node_modules` directory) and use Docker more for distribution and deployment.

Answer (score 1):

### First

> I will create a new docker-container on my computer with the content
>   of the dockerfile? If I need to update anything inside it I have to
>   run it again so the container is updated?

`docker-build` creates an image (like ISO). To create a container, you have to start/run this image. Container is a running image, which can differ from original because during run you can modify the file system inside. When you stop and remove the container, all changes are lost. Docker practice is not to store data in images - if image produces something valuable, it should be stored outside (consider volumes for that).

### Second

```
CMD ["gulp --version" , "gulp"]
```

This is incorrect. JSON notation requires you to put each argument in a separate array element. This is correct:

```
CMD ["guld", "--version"]
```

### Conclusion

You create an image with

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

You start it (create container) with

```
docker run --name=my-image-instance my-image
```

If you need to control running container, you can use friendly name `my-image-instance` or, if you didnt provide it, container's `ID`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It was very helpful but the other one was a bit more detailed about my gulp problem.